# cloning a file system from a crashing disk

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, fsck

I have a Lubuntu 16.04 32-bit, which is installed on a 320gb sata hdd. After some time of use, the hdd began to damage and I could not boot up properly from time to time. But always standard Lubuntu recovery tools helped me. At the end, my MBR was damaged, I was able to restore fs using fsck. After that, I decided to clone the hdd to 1Gb sata3 hdd. At first I decided to use dd. During dd i got a ton of errors and as a result the fs did not boot at all. After that, I formatted the created partition and copied the fs using tar. After that, lubuntu began to boot from the new disk, but from time to time the fs was read only. To fix this, I used live-usb and the fsck command. The fsck usually returned something like this:

```
Inode 13538762 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode. Fix? yes
Inode 14418178 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower. Fix? yes 
Inode 16131779 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower. Fix? yes
...
```

This was repeated many times and I decided to re-clone the fs. This time using gparted I deleted all partitions, then created a new one, formatted it ext4. And cloned the fs using "cp -afv", and then installed grub using grub-install. The lubuntu began to work, but this time after a while the fs again became read-only. I again used live-usb and fsck and again received the following:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 -y
fsck from util-linux 2.30.1
e2fsck 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
/dev/sdb1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 6340227 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? yes
Inode 11261598 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes
Inode 11819838 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11819994 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11829793 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11829932 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11829943 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 13538895 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? yes
Deleted inode 13887261 has zero dtime.  Fix? yes
Inode 13887265 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 14584546 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 14584547 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 16419601 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 16419602 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -47327301 -47327318 -47362566 -47929343 -47945355 -(48034345--48034349) -(58604061--58604083) -(65354289--65354290)
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1444 (1820, counted=1822).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1445 (2138, counted=2139).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1462 (1676, counted=1677).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1463 (1223, counted=1224).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1465 (1647, counted=1652).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1788 (9712, counted=9735).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1994 (12485, counted=12487).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong (15276277, counted=15276312).
Fix? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -11819838 -11819994 -11829793 -11829932 -11829943 -13887261 -13887265 -(14584546--14584547) -(16419601--16419602)
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #1442 (0, counted=2).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #1444 (7360, counted=7363).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #1695 (6367, counted=6369).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #1780 (5403, counted=5405).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #2004 (5358, counted=5360).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong (16196247, counted=16196258).
Fix? yes
/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb1: 4775262/20971520 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 68609768/83886080 blocks
```

I forgot to mention everytime when lubuntu boots, I always have the following promt: "Serios errors were found while checking the disk drive for /. Press I to ignore, ..." I press I and usually the booting continues successfully, but sometimes it does not work and only live-usb and fsck help. How to get rid of it. 
Thank you for your help.